# jQuery text animation plugin and apostrophe

Tags: jquery

I use flipping text jQuery plugin. But I got a problem with an apostrophe.

I write "0% d'additif" and finally it's written as "0% dadditif" without the apostrophe.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/4z2nrqtz/

```
$('.fliptext').flipping_text({
    tickerTime: 12,
    opacityEffect: true,
    tickerCount: 20,
    customRandomChar: false,
    resetOnChange: true
});
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is mostly with the line 86 of the plugin

```
el.append("<span data-ft-bk='" + text.charAt(i) + "' class='ft_char" + i + "'></span>")
```

If the character at position `i` were to be `'`, you are then inserting the apostrophe unescaped into a string that uses apostrophes as string literals for attribute values.

For now, one way I see of fixing this is that you do it the right way and inverse the string literals

```
el.append('<span data-ft-bk="' + text.charAt(i) + '" class="ft_char' + i + '"></span>')
```

It's recommended to always use `"` for attribute values.